# Send/Receive while in an atomic transaction in BizTalk

Tags: sql, wcf, biztalk, transactionscope, biztalk-2013

I have a Biztalk 2013 Orchestration where I am working on an item that is debatching a message using a call to the pipeline.  I am then taking the debatched messages, using them to create SQL WCF Adapter requests to get detail information and then debatch the responses and write it out to they system.

Sample XMLs:

Envelope w/ Orders

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>1</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>2</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>3</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>4</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>5</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>6</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
     <OrderNum>7</OrderNum>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

Gets Debatched into individual Order Messages:

```
<Order>
    <OrderNum>1</OrderNum>
</Order>
  .
  .
  .
```

This is passed into SQL by creating a stored proc call message with the order number as a parameter.

Response:

```
<OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetail>
          <ItemID>1</ItemID>
          <Price>23.40</Price>
    </OrderDetail>
       .
       .
       .
</OrderDetails>
```

I then debatch out to individual OrderDetail records using the pipeline in the orchestration.

Anyway, when i call the SQL Server and get a response, I get an error on compile about

```
"an atomic scope may not contain or call a service or scope that contains both the send and the corresponding receive of a requestresponse operation on a 'uses' port or servicelink".
```

I change the transaction level of the scope object (needed for the debatching) from atomic to long running, and i get this error.

```
"a non-serializable object type 'Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.ReceivePipelineOutputMessages GetBatchPipelineOutput' can only be declared within an atomic scope or service"
```

I need to get the individual items in the list (it can be a long list, hence the reason i used the pipeline) and pass them as arguments to the SQL server, but it seems i can't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you stuck in the Atomic penalty box.  However, what you want can certainly be done if you can accept a change in what you might be your expected behavior.

You can move the subsequent processing, SQL call and such, logic to a Start'ed Orchestration (not a Called) which will escape your debatching Orchestration's Atomic Scope.

However, be aware that the Start'ed Orchestration(s) will not Actually be activated until the original message has been fully debatched because the Start Messages are not committed to the MessageBox until the Atomic Scope completes.

Comment: What about using a C# component to query the SQL server and create an array of messages (or list) and going through that?  I tried the started orchestration solution and while it works, since the orchestrations run on different threads, the data comes back in different order.  I need things in an ordered method (basically, batch and detail info)

Comment: Ok, that's a little...well a lot different ;)  To maintain order, you'd have to use a Sequential Convoy in the second Orchestration.  To do that, you would Publish the debatched message using a Send Shape.  Then in the second Orchestration, pick up the message using an Ordered Receive Port/Shape in a loop.

Comment: So what i ended up doing was like my earlier suggestion.  I created a serializable list of message objects (by converting my XSDs to classes) and appending the message to the variable that was my list object as I debatched.  I then was able to loop through the list outside the atomic scope and do what i needed to with the messages to query the SQL servers.  Overall, performance seems to be pretty good.  Might be that i have relatively small message sizes though.